# Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast: address issue

Tags: iphone, pointers

I want the address for each graphic component I write so I can work off of it later as it is a large matrix and I don't want to do: "`for(UIView *myView in [self.view subviews]){`".  <--too slow to link and often I don't get what I want.

However I can get the desired result by keeping the address and setting the pointer address to it, but I get a Warning:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:RectFrame];
address[j][i] = (int) myView;
myView = address[j][i];   //  <---Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Ok, so I try and cast it with (UIView) and get...

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:RectFrame];
address[j][i] = (int) myView;
myView = (UIView) address[j][i];  //  <---Conversion to non-scalar type requested
```

So how do I appease and clear the warning "ssignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"  ??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: iterating, manipulating and drawing 1000 UIViews is probably going to be unacceptably slow no matter how you do it.  And I'll bet the "drawing" part is going to be your bottleneck, so I doubt the difference between iterating through the `subviews` array or a 2D C array will make a noticeable difference in speed.

That said, to make the warning go away, declare your array as an array of `(UIView *)` pointers instead of `int`:

```
UIView *address[100][10];
```

Then you don't need to do any type casting anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Tag property, then you can use [self viewWithTag:aTag];

Comment: i have a 1000 elements... so i can't be doing searches  :: for(UIView *myView in [self.view subviews]){.  Unless there is another way??

Comment: you don't need to loop.... [myView setTag:1]; then to retrieve it [self.view viewWithTag:1]; will return myView;

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand what you are doing but straight to the answer, it should be

```
myView = (UIView *) address[j][i];
```

Comment: Thank you.  That worked..  I had played with the star outside the curly bracket and it failed.  Forgot to put it inside.